# How to interpret an AUC value of 0.55

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, roc, auc

I have a classifier with an AUC value of 0.55.  I understand that an AUC value of 0.5 is essentially a random classifier and not predictive at all.  So I am wondering if an AUC of 0.55 is significantly larger than 0.5 to say that the classifier is predictive.  As an additional test I looked at some precision values at different thresholds and the precision values were essentially the same as a random classifier.  Can I conclude that this classifier is essentially random even though its AUC is slightly above 0.5?

Comment: Must have been already answered, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpr*+auc++answers%3A1

Comment: One might be able to get confidence intervals around the AUC-ROC. If those do not include 0.5 then we can see that we are picking some signal but on the other hand this signal might be very weak. Put it another way, maybe a bias coin does not have a 50:50 chance for H:T, but rather a 45:55. Assuming that I want to get Tails, this biased coin is preferable to a truly random coin but in reality instead of having a +5% chance of getting Tails is not a major selling point unless the stakes are pretty high and/or I repeat this man times.